# How i can overwrite changes on this file?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, composer-php

I am trying to deploy my Laravel project on my live server, but i have a problem with `composer.json` file

```
no@zz8807:/var/www/html$ sudo git pull origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': whiteG9291
Password for 'https://whiteG9291@github.com': 
From https://github.com/aekraes/zuxweb
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating b19275b..4127e3a
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten 
by merge:
composer.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

this is the error I get.

Notice: I have deployed this before and it worked successfully, but I have done some changes on composer.json permissions

Comment: What is the exact problem? Why not revert the changes, or put them under version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take a pull with uncommitted changes, so to pull changes with some local uncommitted changes you have two option ->

- Stash your changes
- commit your changes

**Stash changes**

```
git stash
git pull origin master
```

If you pop your stashed changes now, you can merge with the pulled changes,

```
git stash apply
```

**Commit changes**

```
git add composer.json
git commit -m "updated composer"
git pull origin master
```

Now you will to merge the data which came from the origin with your local.

After merge in both cases commit your merged changes,

```
git add composer.json
git commit -m "merged"
git push origin master
```

Comment: I get this message when commit 
`no@zz607:/var/www/html$ sudo git commit -m "updated composer"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@zz607.(none)')
`

Comment: You need to tell git what your name and email is, just run the following commands with your email address and name: 
git config --global user.email "YOU@EXAMPLE.COM"';
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME";

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your local changes then commit them to your git repo:

```
git add composer.json
git commit -m 'your message'
git push
```

If you don't want to keep your changes to composer.json, just stash them on the stack and never fetch them down, then you can pull from master

```
git stash
git pull origin master
```